# Count the number of statements per line in C/C++

Tags: count, statements

Given a C program (could be a C++, although for now, i'd stick to C), I want to count the number of statements for every line of code (excluding comments etc of course)

I have been writing a parser to do that - but clearly i keep encountering code that kinda fails.

so if a code line has "i= 0; i++; i--;" on a single line, i want my parser to return 3 for this line. If i have "if (x) { x++}; else x--;" on a single line, then it should return 3 (if, x++, x--). Are there tools that already do this (does pycparser provide an option to return the number of statements in a given line?)

Comment: I don't know about existing tools but you can always use something like LibTooling in clang to write your own probably since it gives you access to the whole AST of compiled code.

Comment: Compiled code -- hmmmm. So If my C file is typically compiled with gcc or icc, I still need to compile it using Clang to get the required info? Or can Clang take the preprocessed output (from gcc - since it contains macros etc expanded) and give me that info?

Comment: Well preprocessed output would likely expand includes and if gcc and clang use different standard libraries that'd cause problems, you're probably better off just compiling it with clang though since unless you're using GCC-specific things it'll likely compile very similarly. There might be such a thing for GCC, like Googling such things mentions it supports plugins which may be able to do the same thing.